# Speeding up py2neo using Cypher

Tags: python, sqlite, neo4j, py2neo

I am populating a graph from an SQLite3 database into neo4j, using py2neo with Python 3.2 on Ubuntu linux. Although speed is not of the utmost concern, the graph has only gotten 40K rows (one relation for each sql-row) in about 3hours, out of a total of 5 million rows.

Here is the main loop:

```
from py2neo import neo4j as neo
import sqlite3 as sql

#select all 5M rows from sql-database
sql_str =  """select * from bigram_with_number"""  

#loop through each row
for (freq, first, firstfreq, second, secondfreq) in sql_cursor.execute(sql_str):

    # create the Cypher query string using cypher 2.0 with merge
    # so that nodes are created only if needed

    query = neo.CypherQuery(neo4j_db,"""
        CYPHER 2.0 
            merge (n:word {form: {firstvar}, freq: {freqfirst}})
            merge(m:word {form: {secondvar}, freq: {freqsecond}}) 
            create unique (n)-[:bigram {freq: {freqbigram}}]->(m) return n, m""")
    #execute the string with parameters from sql-query
    result = query.execute(freqbigram = freq, firstvar = first, freqfirst=firstfreq, secondvar=second, freqsecond=secondfreq)
```

Although the database populates nicely, it will take weeks before it is finished.
I suspect it is possible to do this faster.

Comment: I moved the Cypher query creation out of the loop, and also deleted the `return n, m` statement in it, which gave a five fold speed increase. It is still too slow though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For bulk loading, you're probably better off bypassing the REST interface and using something lower level such as Michael Hunger's load tools: https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-shell-tools. Even at optimal performance, the REST interface is unlikely to ever achieve the speeds you're looking for.

As an aside, please note that I don't officially support Python 3.2 although I do support 3.3.

Comment: Thanks for tip. Ther is also https://github.com/jexp/batch-import which seems to provide the speeds I am looking for.

Comment: Yes, I think `neo4j-shell-tools` have superseded `batch-import` but it would be worth pinging Michael on the mailing list for more info.

Comment: Actually it hasn't they have different goals. `batch-import` is for high performance initial imports. `neo4j-shell-tools` are new shell commands for easier import into running databases.